# Hosting asp.net site with self hosted WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, web

I'm distributing my web application among several customers, deployed on their local IIS instance.
The problem is that iis is not always easy to configure and maintain. Can i use WCF infrastructure in order to host my asp.net web site? (means returning web pages to the browser, not just web services)

Comment: Do you mean that the site will run in a separate windows service (instead of being an IIS web application)?

Comment: If you mean can WCF act like a web server, then no.  WCF is a framework for hosting and interacting with web services.